# IIS7 access website from remote computer

Tags: iis, iis-7

i created a site on my iis7 it's like http://localhost:88/my
i also can access it like this http://myip:88/my
but when a friend of mine from a remote computer tried to access it like this http://myip:88/my it gives him 404 not found

anybody can tell me what should i do to make it work from remote ?

Comment: is you friend's computer on the same network?

Comment: no, my friend's computer is not on the same network

Comment: Related post - [How to connect to a remote IIS with INETMGR on WIndows 7](https://serverfault.com/q/141309/329172)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Check your firewall.  You will have to open TCP Port 88.

> Part 4: Opening Up to the Outside
>   World
>
> Windows Firewall blocks the World Wide
>   Web Services port by default (Port
>   80).  With this port blocked, other
>   machines cannot connect to your web
>   server.  This severely limits the
>   scope of potential web site viewers. 
>   So, in order to show your new web site
>   and server to the outside world you
>   must add an exception to the Windows
>   Firewall.
>
> 1. Click Start and type firewall into the Search bar and press enter.
>      (Note: Make sure you select Windows
>      Firewall and not Windows Firewall with
>      Advanced Security)
> 2. Click Change Settings
> 3. Click the Exceptions Tab and Scroll to World Wide Web Services
>      (HTTP).
> 4. Click the check box and click OK.
>
> Now your machine is accessible to the
>   outside world.  You can connect to
>   your machine by typing in the IP
>   address of your server into another
>   machine’s web browser.

[source](http://blogs.iis.net/rlucero/archive/2007/03/26/iis-7-client-beginner-s-guide.aspx)

Comment: it's working if i disable my firewall, i should find a way to make my it not block this thing

Comment: I added instructions to this answer to open HTTP, but in your case you need to specify TCP Port 88.

Comment: @jinsungy i have disabled firewall and i website is accesed on my pc with ip address but not on another pc

Comment: @jinsungy I see you've asked OP if the request comes from the same network. Is this a requirement for this to work, or following your answer, and me typing my IP address here, would be able to access my localhost site ?

Answer (score 3):

If firewall setting is not the issue (say it's turned off), find out public IP  of your server (ex. 192.168.0.152), then add it to http listener on the server itself
Open cmd and type:
netsh http add iplisten 192.168.0.152

Answer (score 0):

Go  Control Panel>System and Security>Windows Firewall>Allowed Programs-> then check all " World Wide Web Services(Http) tab"

Its is worked for me