# how to configure iis so that I can connect to my iis hosted localhost from a remote windows pc

Tags: asp.net, iis, networking

there must be a load of questions on this but I cant get it working.  I have a asp.net app running locally hosted within iis (windows 8/ version 6.2) which I can browse locally.  Example below, and it works without a problem.

```
  http://localhost:1234
```

I'm trying to browse this site from a windows virtual machine using remote desktop and then launching the browser on the client machine.  Unfortunately this display "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

any ideas why I cant get through on a remote desktop?  The client has internet access obviously and I can ping the other machine (both ways).  Is there an IIS or firewall setting I can configure.  The firewall on the dev box (i.e. the web server in this situation) has a firewall switched on.  When I turn it off I still get the same error message.

My iis authenication settings are shown below (for my website, not for the 'Default Web Site'):

[image]

On the client machine, I'm using the following:

```
  http://12.34.56.78:1234
```

Thanks,
James

Comment: Go to Windows Firewall and open TCP port 1234

Comment: Can you see whether IIS is working by accessing `http://12.34.56.78`?

Comment: Lex Li: I've just added the rule into the firewall and hit refresh.  It's taking a really long time to refresh the page so its definitely trying hard to connect but still waiting for the result (near to 5 minutes time waiting)

Comment: Nilesh: I'll try shortly, as my previous comment to Lex Li is freezing up the browser and I want to see if that works first.  I did try just the IP previously before creating the question and it displayed the same error message.  I'll try again shortly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625345/iis7-access-website-from-remote-computer

Answer (score 0):

Try using https: instead of http: and also to access the website from other PC, you need to enable your Anonymous Authentication. And you also need to Enable the Directory Browsing from IIS settings of website.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping the ip? Disable the firewall on both machines and try.

Let me know