# URL to reach an aspx page outside from network?

Tags: asp.net, iis, networking, ip, ip-address

Sorry for the noob question.

I have a computer which belongs to the network of my office. I installed IIS on my local computer, and put my website to wwwroot. So I am able to access it locally by localhost. I know my LAN IP and WAN IP.

How can I reach that page from outside my network? How do we decide which URL should we use? I think I will need to do some configuration on my Local Network computer which does all the routing as well.

Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you will do port forwarding. Look at [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/) to learn how to do it.

Default port for IIS is 80. You should add an exception for that port in Windows Firewall of your office. Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625345/iis7-access-website-from-remote-computer) for that.

Then outside users can reach your web site like that: http://yourOfficeIP:80/yourApplication.